# Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a weird problem that I started getting out of nowhere.

I have container component that receives data from child components.

This is the constructor where I am declaring the state and binding the functions that will be modifying the state.

```
class HomePage extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.getSelectedImage = this.getSelectedImage.bind(this);
    this.getTargetId = this.getTargetId.bind(this);
    this.handleSend = this.handleSend.bind(this);
    this.state = { targetId: null, targetImage: null };
  }
```

Now I have this function, which changes one state,

```
getSelectedImage(image){

    this.setState({ targetImage: image });
    console.log(this.state.targetImage.id);

  }
```

This works fine. But then I have this,

```
getTargetId(target){
    console.log(target);
    this.setState({ targetId: target });
  }
```

This fails with the error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function
```

I can `console.log` the `target`, so the data is getting passed up right, but then I can't seem to use the same `target` value to change state, using the exact same logic for changing the state of the other object.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing immediately stands out. If you put a breakpoint on at the `this.setState` line in `getTargetId`, what does `this` resolve to?

Comment: I just restarted and things started working. Thanks anyway.